# MYSQL group concat selecting multiple rows

Tags: mysql

Query:

```
SELECT `category`.*, 
       Group_concat(DISTINCT `sub_category`.`english_name` ORDER BY 
       `sub_category`.`order_number` 
       ASC) AS `sub_category`, 
       Group_concat(DISTINCT `sub_category`.`id` ORDER BY 
       `sub_category`.`order_number` 
       ASC) AS `sub_category_id`, 
       Group_concat(`sub_category`.`status` ORDER BY 
       `sub_category`.`order_number` ASC) 
            AS `sub_category_status` 
FROM   `category` 
       LEFT JOIN `item_category` 
              ON `item_category`.`category` = `category`.`id` 
       LEFT JOIN `sub_category` 
              ON `sub_category`.`category` = `category`.`id` 
GROUP  BY `category`.`id` 
ORDER  BY `category`.`order_number` ASC
```

Problematic line:

> Group_concat(`sub_category`.`status` ORDER BY 
>              `sub_category`.`order_number` ASC)

Result:

```
(
        [ID] => 22
        [Create_date] => 2017-11-20
        [Created_by] => 0
        [English_name] => Pens & refills
        [Gujarati_name] => પેન અનેર રીફીલ
        [Header] => False
        [Sidebar] => False
        [Order_number] => 2
        [Status] => Close
        [sub_category] => Botteled Ink,Fountain Pens,gel ink rollball pens
        [sub_category_id] => 54,55,56
        [sub_category_status] => Open,Open,Open,Open,Open,Open,Open,Open,Open,Open,Open,Open,Open,Open,Open,Open,Open,Open
)
```

As you can see I used DISTINCT where I can use. Status either open or close so DISTINCT is not helpful in this column. Can anyone please tell me How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Why the join with table `item_category`? You are not using it anywhere. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: `DISTINCT` wouldn't even be necessary of course, did you not multiply all your sub categories by joining `item_category`.

Comment: You have duplicate `id`s and `english_name` in `sub_category` ? If not then why would you need `DISTINCT` ?

Answer (score 0):

You missed `DISTINCT` For `sub_category_status` Thats why you are getting duplicate value

```
Group_concat(`sub_category`.`status` ORDER BY 
       `sub_category`.`order_number` ASC) 
            AS `sub_category_status`
```

ADD  `DISTINCT` for above column also

```
Group_concat( DISTINCT `sub_category`.`status` ORDER BY 
       `sub_category`.`order_number` ASC) 
            AS `sub_category_status`
```